# Сервер со скриптом и работающей игрой

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, google-chrome

Есть игра не мной написанная, просто браузерная игра. В ней надо фармить, для этого так же есть скрипт(пока на пайтоне если будет надо на любой язык можно перевести). Скрипт работает максимально просто - через передвижение мышки, но для этого требуется пк, который становится полностью неработоспособным. Есть ли какие нибудь сайты чтобы симулировать работу этого пк, желательно бесплатные. Ну или посоветуйте можно ли сделать этот скрипт без участия мышки клавиатуры и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бесплатного в этой жизни ничего не бывает. Покупается сервер (VDS), туда ставится система, запускается скрипт. Для управления браузером (эмуляции браузера) есть Selenuim для Python, PhantomJS.